# Getting unusual error while running my google credentials to update some data in a google sheets

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I have been running a code in python to get data from a management tool called python and once creeating the Dataframe it goes to a google sheets using my Google Credentials and pastes the information. This was working fine and suddenly I tarted getting the error: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/tmp/c66f3b33-d538-469b-8cb0-c65c3d6a9eda'.

I have already tried by renewing my credentials or by creating new ones but it still doesn't work. Does somebody now what exactly could be causing the problem? The error pop-s out when I run this specific part of my code: gc = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file='../CredentialGoogle/sheets.googleapis.com-python.json')

### This is the error I get when trying to authorize my credentials:

```
OSErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-9facbf9c8bda> in <module>()
----> 1 gc = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file='../CredentialGoogle/sheets.googleapis.com-python.json')
      2 sheet = gc.open_by_key('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-Ik')
      3 tab = sheet.worksheet_by_title("Raw Data")
      4 tab.clear(start='A1',end='O10000')
      5 tab.set_dataframe(jiraw_diego, (1,1))

/var/cache/udocker/phoenix-worker/alpha/python2/pygsheets/client.pyc in authorize(outh_file, outh_creds_store, outh_nonlocal, service_file, credentials, **client_kwargs)
    593         else:
    594             raise AuthenticationError
--> 595     rclient = Client(oauth=credentials, **client_kwargs)
    596     return rclient
    597 

/var/cache/udocker/phoenix-worker/alpha/python2/pygsheets/client.pyc in __init__(self, oauth, http_client, retries, no_cache)
     70 
     71         self.oauth = oauth
---> 72         http_client = http_client or httplib2.Http(cache=cache, timeout=20)
     73         http = self.oauth.authorize(http_client)
     74         data_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "data")

/var/cache/udocker/phoenix-worker/alpha/python2/httplib2/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, cache, timeout, proxy_info, ca_certs, disable_ssl_certificate_validation, ssl_version)
   1617         # where cached responses are held.
   1618         if cache and isinstance(cache, basestring):
-> 1619             self.cache = FileCache(cache)
   1620         else:
   1621             self.cache = cache

/var/cache/udocker/phoenix-worker/alpha/python2/httplib2/__init__.pyc in __init__(self, cache, safe)
    935         self.safe = safe
    936         if not os.path.exists(cache):
--> 937             os.makedirs(self.cache)
    938 
    939     def get(self, key):

/home/udocker/phoenix-worker/environments/python2/lib/python2.7/os.pyc in makedirs(name, mode)
    155         if tail == curdir:           # xxx/newdir/. exists if xxx/newdir exists
    156             return
--> 157     mkdir(name, mode)
    158 
    159 def removedirs(name):

OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/tmp/c66f3b33-d538-469b-8cb0-c65c3d6a9eda'
```

I would like to know if somebody knows how to solve the problem since I have already asked for assistance to many persons with experience using google cloud platform and they haven't been able to figure what the problem is

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I am using 2.02 and pygsheets.authorize() does not (maybe has never taken) no_cache as a parameter? If you have found a work around while still using pygsheets please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This is because pygsheets is using temp directory. To fix this, either update to latest pygsheets version or use `no_cache=False` while authorizing pygsheets.